# Using Google Closure Compiler can you exclude a section of source code from the compiled version?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, google-closure-compiler

I recently built a project using the [Dojo toolkit](http://dojotoolkit.org/) and loved how you can mark a section of code to only be included in the compiled version based on an arbitrary [conditional check](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/exclude.html). I used this to **export private variables for unit testing or to throw errors vs. logging them**. Here's an example of the Dojo format, I'd love to know if there are any special directives like this for the [Google Closure Compiler](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/).

```
window.module = (function(){

  //private variable
  var bar = {hidden:"secret"};

  //>>excludeStart("DEBUG", true);
    //export internal variables for unit testing 
    window.bar = bar;
  //>>excludeEnd("DEBUG");

  //return privileged methods
  return {
    foo: function(val){
      bar.hidden = val;
    }
  };
})();
```

**Edit**

*Closure the definitive guide* mentions that you can extend the CommandLineRunner to add your own Checks and Optimizations that might be one way to do it. [Plover](http://code.google.com/p/plovr/) looks promising as it supports [custom-passes](http://www.plovr.com/options.html).

Comment: Do you know you can use the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode with the Dojo Toolkit?  Check out my doc: http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/file/n2636749/Using_the_Dojo_Toolkit_with_the_Closure_Compiler.pdf?by-user=t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Closure Compiler supports "defines",  like this:

```
/** @define {boolean} */
var CHANGABLE_ON_THE_COMMAND_LINE = false;
```

Answer (score 10):

This simple test case worked. Compile with `--define DEBUG=false`

```
/**
 * @define {boolean} DEBUG is provided as a convenience so that debugging code
 * that should not be included in a production js_binary can be easily stripped
 * by specifying --define DEBUG=false to the JSCompiler. For example, most
 * toString() methods should be declared inside an "if (DEBUG)" conditional
 * because they are generally used for debugging purposes and it is difficult
 * for the JSCompiler to statically determine whether they are used.
 */
var DEBUG = true;

window['module'] = (function(){

  //private variable
  var bar = {hidden:"secret"};

  if (DEBUG) {
    //export internal variables for unit testing 
    window['bar'] = bar;
  }

  //return privileged methods
  return {
      foo: function(val){
        bar.hidden = val;
      }
  };
})();

console.log(window['bar']);
module.foo("update");
console.log(window['bar']);
```

Comment: I believe this answer is more correct than the accepted answer, as it uses a built-in (albeit undocumented) Closure option which is more inline with the "correct" way to do things. The answer is also longer, and includes an example.

Comment: @LeeHambley, what? Aside from "long and example", how those answers are different in anything? They both give you `/** @define {boolean} */` annotation.